# How to retrive Facebook Contact for the Native Address book( i.ePeople app) from Motorola RAZR

Tags: android, motorola

I am able to fetch normal contact from Motorola Razr 4.0.4 device by using the below code.

```
private Cursor getContacts()
{
    // Run query
    Uri uri = ContactsContract.Contacts.CONTENT_URI;
    String[] projection = new String[] {
            ContactsContract.Contacts._ID,
            ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME
    };
    String selection = ContactsContract.Contacts.IN_VISIBLE_GROUP + " = '" +
            (mShowInvisible ? "0" : "1") + "'";
    String[] selectionArgs = null;
    String sortOrder = ContactsContract.Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME + " COLLATE LOCALIZED ASC";

    return managedQuery(uri, projection, selection, selectionArgs, sortOrder);
}
```

But I am not able to fetch the facebook contact which has number so that i can show it to user's.

I have searched in stackoverflow  and found  that facebook contact are restricted .

My question is there a  workaround to fetch facebook contact or other groups contact in motorola razr 4.0.4.